# How to get google news custom selection in rss

Tags: rss, google-news

I want to use my custom selection in google news as rss feed in my website. but when i adding it shows general news.
[link to my custom selection](https://news.google.co.il/news/section?pz=1&cf=all&ned=iw_il&hl=iw&csid=d1a71522ea6c38c6&siidp=437a101ed62bc44b54f030d498743000f0d6&ict=ln&rss=true)

I looked everywhere and got no answer

Comment: i tried using &output=rss and it don't work

Comment: https://news.google.co.il/news/section?pz=1&cf=all&ned=iw_il&hl=iw&csid=d1a71522ea6c38c6&siidp=437a101ed62bc44b54f030d498743000f0d6&ict=ln&output=rss

Answer (score 0):

You could try appending `&output=rss` to the URL (instead of `&rss=true`)